# Mouseover/Mouseenter event outside of bounds of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wondering if theres an easy way with jQuery to trigger a mouseover/mouseleave type event on an element plus an extra 20px or so either side

i.e. I have a couple of next/previous buttons that appear outside of the website container using

```
#slider .prev{position:absolute;left:-20px;}
```

because they are currently set to appear

```
#slider:hover{}
```

they disapear when I hover over them being outside the bounds of #slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are triggered based on the border box of the element. One way to hack this is to put an invisible border to your element:

```
border: solid 20px rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

or a padding:

```
padding: 20px;
```

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s40h9nsv/) to demonstrate it.

Comment: The `border` solution doesn't work. The `padding` one does, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Add a container to your element with a padding 20px, and attach the hover event to the container.